# How can I get a value out of an excel workbook stored in SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, excel

I am reposting this question asked about six years ago to see if I can get a less technical or more modern way of achieving the end result:

I am trying to create an automated process that takes some input data from excel workbooks stored in a SharePoint document library. It makes sense for the data to be in Excel (in that it's easy to manage, easy to extend, do calcs, etc.) but some of the data there is required by the automated process, so from that point of view it would be more convenient if it were in a database. To give the information more visibility, workflows, etc.

The problem then would be: how can the automated process extract the values it needs from the Excel workbook that now lives within the SharePoint library?

Are there any new capabilities in excel, excel online or SharePoint that I can use to export the values I need in the workflow? And even if it can be done, is it a sensible thing to do?

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem by using excel services. The biggest challenge I had was configuring it as it was a little fiddly. Once I did have it all connected then it worked brilliantly. In my situation I was using an InfoPath form where data was collected and i needed to perform very complicated calculations - perfect for Excel. I simply passed values into the spreadsheet stored in the library and what was returned to my form was the result.

Comment: How did you get the spreadsheet to return values to your form? Specifically, in my case, I would like to retrieve the value of a cell in the spreadsheet and use it to populate a field in a SharePoint list.